# Keras custom loss function to optimize evaluated probabilities

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

The dataset looks as follows:

```
In [5]: df.head()
Out[5]: 
    _unit_id   category  category:confidence                                          image_url
0  851505458       ikat               0.3487  http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/we-attribute...
1  851505459      plain               1.0000  http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/we-attribute...
2  851505460  polka dot               0.6709  http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/we-attribute...
3  851505461      plain               1.0000  http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/we-attribute...
4  851505462   geometry               0.7035  http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/we-attribute...
```

Here, a `_unit_id` contains a list of images, `image_url` contains the link to it, `category` defines its label(total 17) and `category:confidence` is the probability that the given label is true.
Since the confidence score is not the probability distribution, rather the probability of the most likely class, I thought, if the probability of the first entry(for example) is `0.3487` then the probability of rest of the classes can be uniformly distributed as `(1-0.3487)/16`. Then the probabilities out of softmax and these evaluated probabilities can be optimized via MSE or cross-entropy.
Since the custom loss function takes only `yTrue` and `yPred`, I don't know how to proceed about it. Need hints. If any other effective approach then does suggest!

Comment: Easy way: set category:confidence on all rows as 1.

Comment: Yeah, I could do it, but if it is provided, then there has to be a purpose, no? 
And optimizing it with cross-entropy seemed to me a good way of utilizing it.